# Replace one of values in array if condition is true, in JMESPATH

Tags: jmespath

Here is JSON:

```json
{
  "a": [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

The idea is to replace `bar` by `bar_new`, if `bar` is present in the array.

The desired output will be:

```json
[
  "foo",
  "bar_new",
  "test"
]
```

So, if we don't have `bar` in the input JSON, the output will be:

```json
[
  "foo",
  "test"
]
```

I've tried to put it together by `map()` and `join()` functions, but `join()` function returns a string instead of an array.
I need exactly this array in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, the only caveat is that it does not replace the element `bar`, it removes it out of the array and appends an element `bar_new` if there was an element `bar` in the first place.
So, effectively the element `bar_new` is not guaranteed to be at the same index as `bar` was.

---

In JMESPath you cannot do an `if ... else ...`, but you can apply the same principle as you will sometimes find in shell scripts where we can do

```bash
some_instruction \
  && another_instruction_when_the_first_one_is_successful \
  || yet_another_instruction_when_the_first_one_fail
```

So, in your case you can start by saying:

- if I find `bar` in the array, return me an altered version of the array:

  - without the value `bar`
  - with a new element `bar_new`
- if I don't find `bar` in the array (effectively, an else), return me the array in `a`

Finding an element in an array is quite simple, given that this is the role of the function [`contains()`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains).

Giving you a query like:

```
(contains(a, `bar`) && [`new_array_here`]) || a
```

Knowing how to append an element in an array is a tricky one, there is no easy concatenation between arrays in JMESPath, this said, you can create an array of arrays and *[flatten](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator)* it.

For example:

```
[[`a`,`b`],`c`] | []
```

Would result in

```json
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

---

Combining all of this, the query

```
(contains(a, `bar`) && [a[? @ != `bar`], `bar_new`] | []) || a
```

Would yield, with your example JSON,

```json
[
  "foo",
  "test",
  "bar_new"
]
```